# Algorithm for determining whether certain numbers appear in Pascal's triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there any easy characterisation for the numbers which appear in Pascal's triangle that ARE NOT $\dbinom{n}{1}$, $\dbinom{n}{n-1}$?

Is there a fast way to determine if some number (given its prime factorisation) appears in the described manner?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Just look here: http://oeis.org/A006987.

Comment: The following characterization of your problem might be more evocative to the reader: Which numbers appear at least three elements deep into Pascal's triangle? (Those which are one element deep are all equal to $1=\binom{1}{1}$, and those which are two elements deep are of the form you give.)